# Transform dataframe values with multilevel indices to single column

Tags: python, dataframe

I would like to please ask your advice.

How can I transform the first dataframe into the second, below?

Continent, Country and Location are names of column indices.

Polution_level would be added as the column name of the values present on the first dataframe.

```
     Continent     Asia     Asia        Africa       Europe
       Country     Japan    China       Mozambique   Portugal
      Location     Tokyo    Shanghai    Maputo       Lisbon
Date  
01 Jan 20          250      435         45           137
02 Jan 20          252      457         43           144
03 Jan 20          253      463         42           138
```

```
Continent   Country     Location   Date        Polution_Level
Asia        Japan       Tokyo      01 Jan 20   250 
Asia        Japan       Tokyo      02 Jan 20   252
Asia        Japan       Tokyo      03 Jan 20   253 
...
Europe      Portugal    Lisbon     03 Jan 20   138
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The following should do what you want.

Modules

```
import io
import pandas as pd
```

Create data

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""
      Continent     Asia     Asia        Africa       Europe
      Country     Japan    China       Mozambique   Portugal
      Location     Tokyo    Shanghai    Maputo       Lisbon
Date
01 Jan 20          250      435         45           137
02 Jan 20          252      457         43           144
03 Jan 20          253      463         42           138
"""), sep="\s\s+", engine="python", header=[0,1,2], index_col=[0])
```

Verify multiindex

```
df.columns

MultiIndex([(  'Asia',      'Japan',    'Tokyo'),
        (  'Asia',      'China', 'Shanghai'),
        ('Africa', 'Mozambique',   'Maputo'),
        ('Europe',   'Portugal',   'Lisbon')],
       names=['Continent', 'Country', 'Location'])
```

Transpose table and stack values

```
ndf = df.T.stack().reset_index()
ndf.rename({0:'Polution_Level'}, axis=1)
```

[image]